# how to have multiple vault mount points in a kubernetes externalsecret CRD

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

We have an application where secrets are rendered using Kubernetes CRD. Each secret has many key-value pairs. Now we're migrating to vault external secret and the challenge we face is vaultmountpoint is different for each key inside a secret. Without splitting the secret, how can we achieve this? We're looking for something like this where we'd like to mention both global and secretserver mount points for the same secret based on keys.
Kindly help.

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels :
    app_name: myapp
spec:
  type: Opaque
  backendType: vault
  vaultMountPoint: secretserver
  vaultRole: {{ .Values.k8sExternalSecret.Role }}
  data:
    - name: audit
      key: {{ .Values.k8sExternalSecret.vaultMountPoint }}/audit
spec:
  type: Opaque
  backendType: vault
  vaultMountPoint: global
  vaultRole: {{ .Values.k8sExternalSecret.vaultAccessRole }}
  data:
    - name: client
      key: /global/client
```